# vuex: count is not defined in vue component file

Tags: javascript, laravel-5.3, vuejs2, vuex

Just started to integrate vuex to my laravel application, going through with the sample counter application in the official vuex docs.

**js/components/calculate.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ count }}</p>
    <p>
      <button @click="increment">+</button>
      <button @click="decrement">-</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
<script >
  import store from '../app.js'

  export default {
    computed: {
      count () {

        return store.state.count
      }
    },
    methods: {
      increment () {
        store.commit('increment')
      },
      decrement () {
        store.commit('decrement')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

**js/app.js**

```
const calculate = Vue.component('calculate', require('./components/calculate.vue'));

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment: state => state.count++,
    decrement: state => state.count--
  }
});



const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

Using webpack build

I got  `store.state.count` not defined error in this line `return store.count`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are creating your store in app.js file, (since you haven't mentioned) you need to add

```
const calculate = Vue.component('calculate', require('./components/calculate.vue'));

Vue.use(Vuex) // this line

const store = new Vuex.Store({
  state: {
    count: 0
  },
  mutations: {
    increment: state => state.count++,
    decrement: state => state.count--
  }
});

const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

This goes without saying that you need to import `Vuex` in this file.

after which you need to modify, this part of your code:

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app'
});
```

to

```
const app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  store // if you're vue-cli/babel else use store: store
});
```

And in **js/components/calculate.vue**

```
<template>
  <div>
    <p>{{ count }}</p>
    <p>
      <button @click="increment">+</button>
      <button @click="decrement">-</button>
    </p>
  </div>
</template>
<script >
 // import store from '../app.js' this import is not required

  export default {
    computed: {
      count () {
        return this.$store.state.count
      }
    },
    methods: {
      increment () {
        this.$store.commit('increment')
      },
      decrement () {
        this.$store.commit('decrement')
      }
    }
  }
</script>
```

The import is not required as the `store` is supposed to be accessible to each component of the `vue` instance, to access it, you just need to have access to `$store` property of the `vue` instance which in your component is `this` **(as long as the context doesn't change by means of a callback or something similar.)**

Comment: When i add Vue.use(Vuex); get   `Uncaught TypeError: plugin.apply is not a function`

Comment: Then don't add the `vue.use(Vuex)` part.

Comment: Now the error is gone but  showing another error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'count' of undefined` in  `return store.state.count`

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal do you have an answer for this?? https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42549580/vue-jsvue-router-is-not-constructor-error-in-simple-route