# Vue js;Vue router is not constructor error in simple route

Tags: laravel-5, vuejs2, vue-router

I am trying to implement simple routing with  official route library.

Here is my **app.js**

```
 window.Vue = require('vue');
    window.VueRouter= require('vue-router');

    Vue.use(VueRouter);

const vt=Vue.component('example', require('./components/Example.vue'));

const router = new VueRouter({
      routes:[
        {
          path:'/test',
          component:vt
        }
    ]
})

const app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    router:router
});
```

But i got an error

> app.js:11256 Uncaught TypeError: VueRouter is not a constructor

Comment: Why do you have `window.VueRouter` and not just `VueRouter`, is it needed for laravel?

Comment: Yes its for laravel

Comment: Either use `vue.use(window.vueRouter)` or `import vueRouter from 'vue-router'` or `let vueRouter = require('vue-router')`

Comment: Tried the above solutions all are returns the same error:(

Comment: I am using laravel mixer (build all the scripits into one file like gulp file)

Comment: @AmreshVenugopal your second method is worked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Based on the comments finally i resolved with this import

```
import VueRouter from 'vue-router';
Vue.use(VueRouter);
```

Comment: Just noticed we have to put this in `resources/assets/js/app.js` instead of `resources/assets/js/bootstrap.js`

Comment: You must include this code in `resources/assets/js/app.js`

Comment: It works like a charm. But can you please explain what this code is doing?

Answer (score 10):

*This answer is for any onlookers hoping for a little more insight into the problem.*

There are two solutions here.

### Solution 1: ES  Module Import

In Laravel's default config [at least], `vue-router` is expected to be imported as an es module. So, it should be done at the top of the file.

`import VueRouter from 'vue-router'`

### Solution 2: CommonJS Require

Since `vue-router` router *is* an es module, you will have to explicitly access the `default` property of the CommonJS version of the module.

`const VueRouter = require('vue-router').default;`

### Either Solution

You will have to register Vue Router with Vue.

`Vue.use(VueRouter)`

Comment: Even when the solution bellow is accepted, i like this one more because of the explanation. Thanks! For those who want to implement the VueRouter and are not verry familiar with Vue, this how-to is very easy to follow: https://laravel-news.com/using-vue-router-laravel